# Perl - Hash of hash and columns :(

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I've a set of strings with variable sizes, for example:

AAA23

AB1D1

A1BC

AAB212

My goal is have in alphabetical order and unique characters collected for COLUMNS, such as:

first column : AAAA

second column : AB1A

and so on...

For this moment I was able to extract the posts through a hash of hashes. But now, how can I sort data? Could I for each hash of hash make a new array?

Thank you very much for you help!

Al

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @sessions = (
    "AAAA",
    "AAAC",
    "ABAB",
    "ABAD"
);

my $length_max = 0;
my $length_tmp = 0;

my %columns;

foreach my $string (@sessions){

    my $l = length($string);

    if ($l > $length_tmp){
            $length_max = $l;
    }
}

print "max legth : $length_max\n\n";

my $n = 1;

foreach my $string (@sessions){

    my @ch = split("",$string);

    for my $col (1..$length_max){
        $columns{$n}{$col} = $ch[$col-1];
    }

    $n++;
}

foreach my $col (keys %columns) {

    print "colonna : $col\n";

    my $deref = $columns{$col};

    foreach my $pos (keys %$deref){
            print " posizione : $pos --> $$deref{$pos}\n";
    }

    print "\n";
}

exit(0);
```

Comment: What are you going to do in the fifth and sixth columns, where some characters are missing?

Comment: You say you want unique characters in each column. To a native English speaker with some mathematics training, this means each column should contain no repeated characters, but the expected answers you give for the first and second columns are `AAAA` and `AB1A`. How should numerals sort with respect to alphabetic characters? Given that `A` appears at both the beginning and end of the second column's answer, it doesn't appear to be sorted at all.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is rotating the array.  It doesn't need a hash of hash or anything, just another array.  Surprisingly, neither List::Util nor List::MoreUtils supplies one.  Here's a straightforward implementation with a test.  I presumed you want short entries filled in with spaces so the columns come out correct.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;
use List::Util qw(max);

my @Things = qw(
    AAA23
    AB1D1
    A1BC
    AAB212
);


sub rotate {
    my @rows = @_;

    my $maxlength = max map { length $_ } @rows;

    my @columns;
    for my $row (@rows) {
        my @chars = split //, $row;
        for my $colnum (1..$maxlength) {
            my $idx = $colnum - 1;
            $columns[$idx] .= $chars[$idx] || ' ';
        }
    }

    return @columns;
}


sub print_columns {
    my @columns = @_;

    for my $idx (0..$#columns) {
        printf "Column %d: %s\n", $idx + 1, $columns[$idx];
    }
}


sub test_rotate {
    is_deeply [rotate @_], [
        "AAAA",
        "AB1A",
        "A1BB",
        "2DC2",
        "31 1",
        "   2",
    ];
}


test_rotate(@Things);
print_columns(@Things);
done_testing;
```

Comment: I can't read about array rotation without thinking of this post by Raymond Chen: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/02/8918130.aspx. After reading the body, scroll down to the comment by "640k" for the fun part. "You can even rotate by 10 degrees!"

Comment: Yeah, I too was disappointed when I didn't find a `transpose` in `List::MoreUtils`...

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the output of `%columns` in your code with

```
foreach my $i (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %columns) {
  print join(" " => sort values %{ $columns{$i} }), "\n";
}
```

This gives

```
A A A A 
A A A C 
A A B B 
A A B D
```

But using index numbers as hash keys *screams* that you should use an array instead, so let's do that. To get the columns, use

```
sub columns {
  my @strings = @_;
  my @columns;

  while (@strings) {
    push @columns => [ sort map s/^(.)//s ? $1 : (), @strings ];
    @strings = grep length, @strings;
  }

  @columns;
}
```

Given the strings from your question, it returns

```
A A A A
1 A A B
1 A B B
2 2 C D
1 1 3
2
```

As you can see, this is unsorted and repeats characters. With Perl, when you see the word unique, always think of hashes!

```
sub unique_sorted_columns {
  map { my %unique;
        ++$unique{$_} for @$_;
        [ sort keys %unique ];
      }
      columns @_;
}
```

If you don't mind destroying information, you can have `columns` sort and filter duplicates:

```
sub columns {
  my @strings = @_;
  my @columns;

  while (@strings) {
    my %unique;
    map { ++$unique{$1} if s/^(.)//s } @strings;
    push @columns => [ sort keys %unique ];
    @strings = grep length, @strings;
  }

  @columns;
}
```

Output:

```
A
1 A B
1 A B
2 C D
1 3
2
```